# Excel formula needed: sum all data to the right of identified phrase

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to create a formula that will allow excel to find the first instance of the phrase "Prior Stage Not Completed" across a row of columns and then sum the values of all columns in the row from that first instance to the end of the table. There is other data beyond the boundary of the table so it must stick within the area of the table I've defined.

**Thanks in advance for your help.**

[image: Table of data I'm working with]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INDEX/MATCH to return the first cell with that phrase and then anchor the last cell in the row in the table:

```
=SUM(INDEX(M2:U2,MATCH("Prior Stage Not Completed",M2:U2,0)):U2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @Cet533 please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.